# How do I get the correct rgb value for a pixel with GD?

Tags: perl, gd, rgb, pixel

I have a 4x1 pixel png where the left most pixel is white (#ffffff), the second pixel is red (#ff0000), the third pixel is green (#00ff00) and the right most pixel is blue (#0000ff), almost invisible here: [image].

With the following perl script, I tried to read the rgb values for each pixel:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use GD;

my $image = new GD::Image('white-red-green-blue.png') or die;

for (my $x=0; $x<4; $x++) {
  my $index = $image->getPixel($x, 0);
  my ($r,$g,$b) = $image->rgb($index);

  printf "%3d %3d %3d\n", $r, $g, $b;
}
```

Much to my surprise, it printed

```
252 254 252
252   2   4
  4 254   4
  4   2 252
```

whereas I expected

```
255 255 255
255   0   0
  0 255   0
  0   0 255
```

Why does the script report wrong rgb values and how can I teach it to report the correct ones?

**Edit** As per *mpapec*'s question, the output of `base64 white-red-green-blue.png` is

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAQAAAABCAIAAAB2XpiaAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1B
AACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAASSURBVBhXY/gPBAwMDEDM8B8AL90F
+8V5iZQAAAAASUVORK5CYII=
```

**Edit II** As per *dgw*'s suggestion, I also tried `my $image = newFromPng GD::Image('white-red-green-blue.png') or die;` but with the same result.

**Update**: I have tried the same thing with `Image::Magick` instead of `GD`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Image::Magick;

my $image = Image::Magick->new or die;
my $read = $image -> Read('white-red-green-blue.png');

for (my $x=0; $x<4; $x++) {

  my @pixels = $image->GetPixels(
      width     => 1,
      height    => 1,
      x         => $x,
      y         => 0,
      map       =>'RGB',
      #normalize => 1
  );

  printf "%3d %3d %3d\n", $pixels[0] / 256, $pixels[1] / 256, $pixels[2] / 256;

}
```

and, somewhat unsurpringly, it prints the expected

```
255 255 255
255   0   0
  0 255   0
  0   0 255
```

Comment: Have you tried using `newFromPng` instead of `new`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated**

Ok, it works fine with your image if you do this:

```
GD::Image->trueColor(1);
```

BEFORE starting anything with GD. I think it is because one image is palettized and the other is not. See here:

[image]

**Original Answer**

It works fine on my iMac. I generated the image with ImageMagick like this:

```
convert -size 1x1! xc:rgb\(255,255,255\) xc:rgb\(255,0,0\) xc:rgb\(0,255,0\) xc:rgb\(0,0,255\) +append wrgb.png

./go.pl
255 255 255
255   0   0
0 255   0
0   0 255
```

I suspect your image is not being generated correctly.

Comment: Please have another look - I think I have cracked it.

Comment: `GD::Image->trueColor(1);` did the trick. Thank you very much!

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger this is interesting, but there still remains the fact that you can have "pure" colors within palette without resorting to `trueColor`.

Answer (score 2):

Your source image is not pure RGB as you've expected, but you can generate one if you want that,

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use GD;

my $image = new GD::Image('white-red-green-blue.png') or die;
my @c = (
  [255,255,255],
  [255,0,0],
  [0,255,0],
  [0,0,255],
);
for my $x (0 .. 3) {
  ##
  $image->setPixel(
    $x,0, $image->colorAllocate(@{ $c[$x] })
  );
  ##
  my $index = $image->getPixel($x, 0);
  my ($r,$g,$b) = $image->rgb($index);

  printf "%3d %3d %3d\n", $r, $g, $b;
}
```

output

```
255 255 255
255   0   0
  0 255   0
  0   0 255
```

---

```
echo 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAQAAAABBAMAAAALEhL+AAAAGFBMVEUEAvwE/gT8AgT8/vz/////
AAAA/wAAAP/i4quSAAAAC0lEQVQImWNwTQcAAPQArQCZcI0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=' |
base64 -d > new.png
```

Comment: The thing is: if I open my "not so pure image" with an image program and use the "pipette" to choose a color, the colors *are* pure (255/255/255 etc). I really don't understand what's going on here.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger I would question your image program. `new.png` should give same RGB results in perl and 'pipette'.

Comment: Try posting your image - then we can see for ourselves.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I've already posted the image. As it is only 4x1 pixels in size, it's almost invisible, it's in the question right after *almost invisible here:* and looks like an ellipsis. The link to the picture is: http://i.stack.imgur.com/u5VW5.png